# How can I create a custom listview item in kivy?

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I'm trying to to create a custom listview item for a listview in python 3.3 using kivy.

A listitem should consist of a label and 3 buttons.

I created a listview with the adapter cls set to a custom item class as follows:

```
        ListView:
            id: cue_list
            adapter: ListAdapter(data=[], cls=ListItemButton)
            item_strings: []
```

I then set class rules like this:

```
<ListItemButton>:
    size_hint_y: root.size_hint_y
    height: root.height
    orientation:"horizontal"
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.2, 1.0
        text: "delete"
```

then in my python file I create a function to add some items:

```
    def addcue(self):
        self.lv.adapter.data.extend(["new item"])
        self.lv._trigger_reset_populate()
```

But strangely, the result is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNmz1.png

How can I specify a listview item from scratch in kivy, using the .kv file language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widgets have the properties and styling of ListItemButton because...well, that's how inheritance works. If you don't want this, create your own list item widget subclassing `http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#kivy.uix.listview.SelectableView`. For instance, ListItemButton is a subclass of `SelectableView` and `Button`.

Also, all your delete buttons overlap because the ListItemButton is not a layout and so does nothing with the size_hint information you give, therefore all the buttons have the default pos of 0,0 and the default size of 100,100. If you want layout behaviour, make your list item class a layout, e.g. a subclass of `BoxLayout` and `SelectableView`.